# How to remove data link layer from pcap file?

Tags: wireshark, packet, pcap, editcap

I'm making a script that is inspecting packets, but headers giving me a headache. I have a DSL connection/Wireless at home, and the data link layer is appearing in Wireshark capture, either PPP or WLAN depending on which one I am currently using.

I've been searching for a thsark, editcap or tcpdump or whatever tutorial but I couldn't find any.

Basically all I need: < program_name_which_nicely_removes_transport_layer > input.pcap < output.pcap_only_containing_ethernet_header+ip+tcp+data > or something similar.

I have found a program named bittwiste, but it's operating with fixed sizes as I realized, but I need something 'universal', where I don't have to determine the used link type + size.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the OSI model the transport layer is Layer 4 (TCP, UDP) which sits on top of the network layer (layer 3, e.g. IP) which itself sits on top of the data link and physical layer (Ethernet). With the usual PPPoE you have on top of Ethernet (data link) various encapsulations inside the network layer, e.g. IP encapsulated inside  PPP encapsulated inside PPPoE. 

So what you probably don't want is to remove the transport layer (TCP, UDP), but instead remove the PPP and PPPoE encapsulations within the network layer so that only IP is left.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, my mistake, I wanted to write data link layer. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: No, you don't want to remove the data link layer (ethernet), but you want to remove some encapsulation from the network layer. So you don't want to remove the lowest layer, but something in the middle.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Perl and the libraries Net::Pcap and Net::PcapWriter you could do the following to remove the PPPoE layer. This works at least for my router (fritz.box). This needs to be adapted to other encapsulations:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# usage: pcap_remove_pppoe.pl infile.pcap outfile.pcap

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Pcap qw(pcap_open_offline pcap_loop pcap_datalink :datalink);
use Net::PcapWriter;

my $infile = shift or die "no input file";
my $outfile = shift;  # use stdout if not given

my $err;
my $pcap = pcap_open_offline($infile,\$err) or
    die "failed to open $infile: $err";
my $ll = pcap_datalink($pcap);
die "expected DLT_EN10MB, got $ll" if $ll != DLT_EN10MB;
my $offset = 14; # DLT_EN10MB

# open and initialize output
my $pw = Net::PcapWriter->new($outfile);

# process packets
pcap_loop($pcap, -1, sub {
    my (undef,$hdr,$data) = @_;
    my $dl = substr($data,0,$offset,''); # remove data link layer
    my $etype = unpack("n",substr($dl,-2,2)); # get ethernet type
    $etype == 0x8864 or return; # ignore any type except PPPoE Session

    substr($data,0,8,''); # remove 8 byte PPPoE layer
    substr($data,-2,2,pack("n",0x0800)); # set ethernet type to IPv4

    # output: data link layer with IP type + IP layer (PPPoE removed)
    $pw->packet($data, [ $hdr->{tv_sec},$hdr->{tv_usec} ]);
},undef);
```